# Should exception thrown if variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript

`if (e.message.indexOf('x') !== -1) { console.log('Error') } else { throw e }`

I think if e or e.message is undefined, the throw e won't be executed right?

The code below is better right?

`if (e?.message?.indexOf('x') !== -1) { console.log('Error') } else { throw e }`

Comment: Why would either of those be undefined? Defensive programming for its own sake is bad.

Answer (score -1):

tl;dr: Yes, the second variant is probably what you want to use here.

Trying to access a property or function of `undefined` or `null` *will* throw a [`TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError). So, in

```js
if (e.message.indexOf('x') !== -1)
```

If any of `e`, `e.message`, `e.message.indexOf` are `undefined` or `null`, js will throw a `TypeError`, meaning that no, *your* error won't get thrown, but a `TypeError` will.

Even if `e.message` is a valid object, if it does not have an `indexOf()` function, it will still throw a `TypeError`. The reason for this is that trying to access a property of an object if that property does not exist will either

- evaluate to `undefined` if you use it as a value, or
- throw a `TypeError` if you try to use it as a function, i.e. if you try to call it by using `()`.

And yes, the second variant

```
if (e?.message?.indexOf('x') !== -1)
```

solves that problem, by using the [`?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator: If any of `e`, `e.message`, `e.message.indexOf` are `undefined` or `null`, the left-hand side will evaluate to `undefined`:

> The `?.` operator is like the `.` chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (`null` or `undefined`), the expression short-circuits with a return value of `undefined`. When used with function calls, it returns undefined if the given function does not exist.